# When are these diameter errors are triggered?

Tags: lte, diameter-protocol, ims

Can you give examples of when these diameter errors are triggered by the diameter server?

> Error_User_Unknown(5001) and Unknown_Session_ID (5002) in the LTE world

Answer (score 1):

According to the specifications 5001 and 5002 occurs when IMSI and session ID are not found in the database.

There can be many scenarios when this can happen:

- > IMSI has deregistered or move to some other HSS or you receive the message because of error in the peer node.
- > Session terminated and you receive the message thereafter.